# What permissions need to be on files in org-mobile directories?

Tags: linux, emacs, org-mode

I am trying to keep the permissions consistent in my org-directory and staging directory for org-mobile. Both directories are owned by another user (used for syncing on the phone) that shares the same group as my standard user on my local machine. All files and directories are readable and writable by user/group: e.g. `mobileuser.mobileorg` owns all files. However, when I call `org-mobile-push`, I get the error `Doing chmod: Operation not permitted, /home/mobileuser/staging/file.org`.

This was working before I messed with it, but I don't know what the original permissions were, and the Org-mode manual is not enlightening on the subject. I tried `770`, `775`, and `774` with no luck. Even `777` did not satisfy org-mode.

If I change the owner to the emacs user, chmod succeeds, but the permissions aren't actually changed. If the emacs user owns the files, MobileOrg can't sync the files through SSH.

Comment: You say it was working before you messed with it.  What did you mess with?

Comment: The only thing I touched was the permissions, as far as I can recall.

Comment: The error message points to the permissions for the directory, rather than the files.

Comment: Both `/staging` and `/orgs` are `777`, and their permissions didn't change when ownership was changed to emacsuser to allow the push command to go through.

Comment: If it's the directory, what permissions are needed to give emacs running under `emacsuser.mobileorg` to chmod?

Comment: A workaround is to change ownership to `emacsuser.mobileorg` and enable the setgid bit, but that's not ideal.

Comment: Is this a better fit for Super User?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a problem in emacs.

http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=16133

fixed in

http://bzr.savannah.gnu.org/lh/emacs/trunk/revision/115805

on 2013-12-29.

Comment: For reference, the local filesystem is ext3.

Comment: @bitoiu The bug applies to any filesystem where emacs doesn't have permission to change the UID and GID. That happens to frequently include FAT filesystems, but equally applies to files owned by other users on, say ext3, which *is* the original problem.